# How to debug web page rendering compatibility issues across browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing a web page primarily using Firefox. Often I encounter that my web page renders properly in Firefox but has some unexpected behavior in Chrome and IE.

Generally if its related to javascript, I usually open Developer Console in Chrome and see if there were any errors and that gives me a clue as to what might be wrong.
Unfortunately, I am generally lost if its a CSS related or HTML element issue.

In one particular case, I have placed a div inside a `<td>` and I am lost as to why the chrome cannot render it properly irrespective of the fact that firefox is happy and does not complain.

So my question is, how to debug issues related to rendering of HTML pages in Chrome and CSS and determine what might be offending.

My related question is, is there a guidelines to make my web page work in almost all the popular browsers with little effort? I am particularly thinking in terms of tool or process which will warn me of compatibility issues with my web page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IE (Internet Explorer)` and `little effort` doesn't match to each other, you have to invest more of your time and effort only for `IE`, illuminate `IE` and be happy, as a suggestion, use [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) if possible, it's a ready and tested `css` framework (maybe framework is not perfect name).

Basically, as far as I know, only a [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) could be used to gain some consistency but still you have to test over different browsers because each has different [rendering engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser_engine). If you want to keep `IE` in the list then test the layout for `IE` at first.

Only for the `IE` or `Inconsistent Exposer` (IMO) there is a developer tool available ([IE Tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)) to test layout (HTML/CSS) over different versions of `IE` and only works on `Windows` so it may help you a bit if you are `Windows` user. There is also an online tester available and sometimes helpful, it's [browsershots.org](https://browsershots.org/).

Also `IE` has a debugger/developer tool and pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> will bring it so you may see something like this:

[image]

`Google Chrome` has it's built in debugger/inspector (<kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + I</kbd>) and on `Firefox` you may use `Firebug` extension and these browsers are not dumb like `IE` and there are lots of debugging extensions available for these browsers for free, not worried about these good guys.

---

Generally speaking, `IE` users are dumb and used to see dumb things on their screen so I don't think too much about them because they really don't know the difference but as a developer you may need to think about it and in this case I would demand extra charge from my clients if they want me to make a site compatible for `IE < 10` because it requires extra effort.

[You dunno me ? Leh--hoo-zehar (Looser)](http://www.pinterest.com/ijoomla/internet-explorer-jokes-and-funny-pictures/) [image]   [`IE` am a legendhhh. Smooky...!](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/subcultures/internet-explorer)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any tool that will warn you because there is no way for a tool to validate the result of what you desire.

As far as how to test HTML/CSS. Chrome supports the most HTML-5 and FF is a close second. If you develop in chrome it normally works in FF and via verse. IE is where the pain is. IE does not support all HTML tags and often will render things wonky. I normally create my webpage and focus on FF and chrome once I like the results I open IE and debug. 98% of the time it is CSS changes that need to be made. I debug CSS first and if I am not able to resolve it with CSS after a decent amount of work I will look into changing the HTML. I try to avoid changing HTML because you have to debug all other browsers again.

Answer (score 0):

Styles and code developed in Chrome will generally work in Safari, Opera(same engine), and IE 10+ with few inconsistencies. You'll get a few rare positioning issues with some CSS3 specs in Firefox, specifically in background positioning. You'll also find some javascript issues unique to Firefox.

IE9 is generally a good sport and usually doesn't have too many issues. IE8 will have a few and they'll be significantly different based on the OS (as there are multiple versions of each IE and they all support different specs for Javascript and HTML) specifically you'll find lots of issues with XP IE8 and really shouldn't support it (Microsoft doesn't even want to).

For the most part you'll be developing to IE inconsistencies unless it's a CSS3 spec with the occasional javascript strangeness (which js frameworks generally can help with since a few of them were made with that goal in mind).

As far as tools, browserstack is nice but doesn't give you a lot of time. If what you're trying to use is modern [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/) is a good place to visit first. Almost all issues between non-IE browsers will be HTML5 or CSS3 specific though.